# Anything similar to SqlSoup for Scala?

Tags: sql, scala

Which existing Scala database API is most similar to SqlSoup for Python (part of SqlAlchemy)? What I see in SqlSoup: a convenient and largely portable database API where I don't have to specify schemas and all the types are inferred via reflection, yet I don't have to write raw SQL expressions. Also preferable is the fact that it's part of a more complete database package that does support "everything else" (schema specifications, ORM, etc.), and they share many of the same query abstractions. I imagine that Scala 2.9's Dynamic type may come in handy here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The most similar is SQLAlchemy 0.6 http://www.sqlalchemy.org/news.html which supports Jython. That means that you can use SQLAlchemy on the JVM and call it from Java or Scala. Check this for more details http://www.rexx.com/~dkuhlman/jython_course_03.html#calling-jython-from-java

You will likely need to write some interface code in Jython.

The inefficiencies of SQLAlchemy come from the impedance mismatch between SQL and object oriented thinking. Now that you have chosen a non-object oriented language, maybe it is time to move away from SQLAlchemy clones and work on a threadpool to give you non-blocking access to SQL databases. Actors work real well when you break down the problem into lots of small simple tasks and SQLSoup seems too heavy for this.

Maybe you would also benefit from a memcache in front of your SQL database. Imagine that you need to process an SQL request through 7 steps to get the data in the form that you want. If you save all the intermediate results in memcache you may be able to reduce the number of times that you hit the SQL db. Actors lend themselves to a loosely couple design where you can replace an actor or insert two in the place of one.

Comment: We actually moved away from Python + SQLAlchemy for performance reasons - spent too much time hacking around the guts of SQLAlchemy. I guess I should have explicitly stated that I expect the API  to be in a compiled language (e.g. Scala, Java).